# Unity Accord.net Gabor

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, filtering, accord.net

I have to use Gabor Filter on image in Unity. Accord.net have it. I download libs for .net3.5 but i got reflection problem

[link to accord.net](https://code.google.com/p/accord/downloads/list)

> Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
>   Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

i use options changings from subset to .net 2.0 but still nothing.
https://github.com/accord-net/framework/releases

i have to use probably only accord.dll and accord.imaging.dll

what i have to do? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually resolve the dependencies, like this:
[image: plugins]

I got **Accord** DLLs using NuGet, and drag-and-dropped them into Unity from "packages/Accord??/lib/net35". (This means DLLs were built for .NET 3.5.) Maybe you can use manually built DLLs for .NET 3.5.

For Mac OSX, **System** DLLs can be obtained from 
"/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/lib/mono/2.0".